# Proxy is not getting disabled on my Linux Mint Server?

Tags: linux, proxy, linuxmint

I have unset all the proxy environment variables and also changed the proxy to None under Network Proxy. Despite doing this whenever I am running sudo apt-get update it tries to connect to the proxy server. Where s the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed from comment to answer.

Check your proxy configuration for apt in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` (maybe a file called `proxy`) or `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.